# Trigger sum of two columns into 3rd SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to set a trigger in Microsoft Server Manager where a 3rd gets populated by a trigger

Eg. I have a table that contains

- Column 1: Amount
- Column 2: AdminFee
- Column 3: TotalAmount

I need each new row in column3 (total amount) to be populated by Amount + AdminFee

I have the following script but it is not updating Column 3

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateActualAmount 
ON Event 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE BankTransaction 
    SET ActualAmount = Amount + AdminFee
END
GO
```

Can anyone let me know Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your trigger is only triggered when inserting a new row, not on an update. Is that really what you want?!

Comment: Why don't you simply make ActualAmount a calculated column? (Your trigger code is updating all rows)

Comment: And the question is, why would you update BankTransaction table (all rows) whenever something is inserted in [Event] table?

Answer (score 0):

Run this one time:

```
ALTER TABLE BankTransaction DROP COLUMN ActualAmount;
ALTER TABLE BankTransaction ADD ActualAmount as (Amount+AdminFee)
```

Though tbh I'd be doing this in the front end as I don't really feel this kind of calculation has any business case for being part of the table..

If you're desperate to store the result of this sim as a table column and you want to index/query it, then make it a PERSISTED column..